# Getting started with Tweepy 2.1

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying this example

```
import tweepy

public_tweets = tweepy.api.public_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print tweet.text
```

But i am getting this error.

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 301
```

Any suggestions or places where I can find example projects that use tweepy?

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/15479

Comment: Suggestions for places to look for exaples of tweepy? I'd recommend searching StackOverflow for 'tweepy' and working from there.

Answer (score 1):

What tweepy version you use **in fact**? Run

```
python -c "import tweepy; print(tweepy.__version__)"
```

Public timeline is Twitter [API 1.0 endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/public_timeline), and doesn't exists in Twitter API 1.1.

[Removed from tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/189) a year ago.

Comment: @Robert it is indeed strange that you managed to run `public_timeline` then. But either way this api is depricated by twitter.